# Heroku new app has smaller slug than upgrade app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to [upgrade to Heroku Cedar 14](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration#upgrading-the-production-app-to-cedar-14).

As they recommended in the link above, I started by pushing the latest version of my repo to a brand new "staging app", and (after upgrading from Ruby 2.1.1 to Ruby 2.1.7) it succeeded with a slug size of 269MB.  I then upgraded my existing app to Cedar 14.  When I pushed (the exact same repo) to the upgraded existing app, the slug was 429MB.  How is this possible if I'm pushing the same code?

Comment: Who knows or cares? Heroku manages the slug compiler and structure. Did you try asking them? "Slugs are compressed and pre-packaged copies of your application optimized for distribution to the dyno manager." Maybe they did something as simple as adopting a better compression algorithm. Maybe they now share stuff in the new stack that used to be included as static copies. Be happy! Curiosity is good, but Heroku improving their slug system is not a surprise.

Comment: It matters a lot, as the max slug size is 300MB.

Comment: Duh. Sorry I misread the numbers. Thought the slug got smaller.